# Problem with insert table of contents with hyperref

Tags: hyperref

Why do I get some error like

> Paragraph ended before `\Hy@setref@link` was complete

when I insert table of contents in `book` class documents and the error dissapear when I place a comment in `\usepackage{hyperref}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen when you have a faulty `.aux` file which is corrupted during a previous compile that could have had an error in it. Remove the faulty `.aux` file, and recompile (at least twice).